# React native and microsoft android simulator

Tags: react-native

I have installed Microsoft's Android simulator and I can't run any project with `react -native run-android`.

I have tried some ways without success.

Comment: Can you list what you have tried, so people can learn more about your context

Comment: i have to use hyper v for windows i have to use docker same time,

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add this information in it .

Answer (score 0):

1) command is without space: `react-native run-android`
2) Pls install Android Studio, create emulator with target device and api version, run it, and then run cmd from 1st point

Comment: i have to use hyper v for windows i have to use docker same time,  android simulator doesnt support hyper v